# Advanced JTable list of data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to create listbox in option "add new record" JTable and list of items in Jtable.

My model:

```
  namespace CRM.ViewModels.Administrator.Dictionary.OfferNewInformation
    {
        public class DictionaryNewInfoListModel : DictionaryListModel
        {
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public bool IsActiveYN { get; set; }
            public bool CPGroupType { get; set; }
            public bool TCPGroupType { get; set; }
            public bool CCGroupType { get; set; }
            public bool HOGroupType { get; set; }
            public bool TSGroupType { get; set; }
            public int CityId { get; set; }
            public List<DictionaryNewInfoSupportList> DeestynationName { get; set; }

          //  public IList<SelectListItem> DestinationList { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

Important thing (this class have list Id and Name):

```
public List<DictionaryNewInfoSupportList> DeestynationName { get; set; }
```

Class

```
public class DictionaryNewInfoSupportList
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}
```

In View I show example:

```
fields: {
                    Id:
                    {
                        key: true,
                        create: false,
                        edit: false,
                        list: false
                    },
                    Description: {
                        title: 'Treść'

                    }/*,
                    DeestynationName: {
                        title: 'Treść'

                    }*/,
                    CPGroupType: {
                        title: "CP",
                        edit: true,
                        type: 'checkbox',
                        values: { 'false': 'Nie', 'true': 'Tak' }
                    },
                    TCPGroupType: {
                        title: "TCP",
                        edit: true,
                        type: 'checkbox',
                        values: { 'false': 'Nie', 'true': 'Tak' }
                    },
                    CCGroupType: {
                        title: "CC",
                        edit: true,
                        type: 'checkbox',
                        values: { 'false': 'Nie', 'true': 'Tak' }
                    },
                    HOGroupType: {
                        title: "Centrala",
                        edit: true,
                        type: 'checkbox',
                        values: { 'false': 'Nie', 'true': 'Tak' }
                    },
                    TSGroupType: {
                        title: "Kasjer",
                        edit: true,
                        type: 'checkbox',
                        values: { 'false': 'Nie', 'true': 'Tak' }
                    }
```

but as you can see I don`t know how declare DeestynationName.

List of items(example - what I need)

```
if(DeestynationName.id==model.id) show list of Name
```

In "add new record" I need listbox with elements which are in this list (example - what I need):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CurrentVoucher, new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(Model.DictionaryNewInfoSupportList, "Id", "Name"), new { style = "width:140px" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I start thinking about this problem and it is very difficult. I try add "partial view" but I get error : It is no possible to load list for CityId

This error I Get - When in options I put this partial View. If I will remove only this line, project is compiled correct. Of Course if I remove this option I have empty place in list but list of data working correct. Of Course I need this partial View.

```
            CityId: {
                title: 'City',
                width: '11%',
                options: '@Url.Action("GetCityOptions")'
            },
```

and I added Controller:

```
namespace dd
{
    [Themed]
    public class AdministratorController : DefaultController
    {
        [CustomAuthorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetCityOptions()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

and partial View to understand the problem.

```
@model CRM.ViewModels.Administrator.DictionaryModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetCityOptions";
}

<h2>GetCityOptions</h2>
dfsfdsfds
```